# How to get name of variable in method?

Tags: javascript, object, browser

How to get name of variable in method?

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, "toDataURL", { "value": function ({
       console.log(this.getContext('2d'))
       //name of caller here
       console.log("param is ", this.caller)
       return "data:,"
    } 
});
```

For example

```
var canvasParam = document.createElement("canvas");
canvasParam.width = 400;
canvasParam.height = 200;
//<....>
var str = canvasParam.toDataURL("image/png");
```

In Console:

> param is canvasParam

Comment: `var str = canvasParam.toDataURL("image/png");` <-- **Please** don't use `data:` URIs: they're slow, they block the main thread, and they waste memory. Why not use Object URLs and/or `Blob` objects instead? It's **waaaaayyy** faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The names of variables are not accessible to runtime code (and may not even exist after optimization is applied to it). Moreover, there may not even *be* a variable to get the name of (`document.createElement("canvas").toDataURL()`). If you want information in `toDataURL`, pass it into `toDataURL` as a parameter. (Or put it somewhere on the object and access it via `this`.)

---

Side note: `canvasParam` isn't a parameter, it's a variable. *Parameters* are the things declared in the parameter list of a function, for instance `example` in `function someFunction(example)`. (Related: When you *call* a function, for instance `someFunction(x)`, what you're passing it [`x` in that example] are *arguments*. The value of the argument is determined and passed to the function where it's received in the parameter as the parameter.)

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the source code, it's obfuscated

Comment: @НиколайСычев - That doesn't change the answer. You can't get the name of that variable from within `toDataURL`.